# Pic Display cycle between 5 and 0

Tags: c++, display, pic

Here is our code. We tried to make the display cycle between 5-0, but it's stuck at 5.

```
void main()
{
    unsigned char count=0;
    unsigned char table[]={0x3F,0x06,0x5B,0x4F,0x66,0x6D,0x7D,0x07,0x7F,0x6F};
    TRISC=0;

    while(1) {

        for(count=0;count<6;count++) {
            PORTC=table[count];
            delay_ms(59);
            if(count==5 && count>=0)
            {
               count -= count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It goes to 5, but it's not coming back to 0.

Our proteus design and other stuff is true. The only problem is in the code we wrote.

Pic 16F877A

Comment: `count==5 && count>=0` has same dichotomy with `count==5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if-statement decreases the count from 5 to 4, but the for-loop then increases the value back to 5. Once the `count` reaches 5, this will repeat forever. You'll need to re-design the logic to get an up-ramp/down-ramp behavior (that cycles between 0 and 5). Try something like this:

```
void main()
{
    unsigned char count=0;
    unsigned char table[]={0x3F,0x06,0x5B,0x4F,0x66,0x6D,0x7D,0x07,0x7F,0x6F};
    TRISC=0;

    bool increment = true;
    while(1) {

       PORTC=table[count];
       delay_ms(59);

       // Increment or decrement.
       count += increment ? 1 : -1;
       // Switch from incrementing to decrementing (or vice versa).
       if (count >= 5 || count <= 0) {
            increment = !increment;
       }
   }
}
```

This defines a boolean flag `increment` to designate whether we are incrementing or decrementing the `count` variable. When `count` gets to the upper or lower bound, the `increment` flag gets inverted.